# Peer Dependency warning in angular v 4.0.0

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack-2, typescript2.1

I have updated the angular packages version from 2.4.10 to 4.0.0. After running 'npm install' command it throw's following message

```
    npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^2.3.0, required by @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.2
    npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^2.0.0, required by angular2-flex@1.0.3
    npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^2.3.0, required by @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.2
    npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^2.0.0, required by angular2-flex@1.0.3
```

And my installed packages list is below

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.3.0",
    "angular2-recaptcha": "^0.4.0",
    "angular2-flex": "^1.0.3"
}
```

And in webpack.common.js changed the configuration

```
new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
            helpers.root('./src'),// location of your src
            {} // a map of your routes
        )
```

Comment: are you using the stablw angular 4 release or the Rc

Comment: Yes I am using stable angular 4.0.0. Please refer the link https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-rc1-2017-02-24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@angular/material` package requires angular 2, so it's not compatible with angular 4. By the [semantic versioning rules of npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004), `^2.3.0` allows only version greater than or equal to `2.3.0` but still with the major version 2, so only `2.x.y` where `x >= 3`.

You'll have to wait until they release a version for Angular 4. When the pull request [#3752](https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/3752) is merged, you could use the master branch as described in [Readme - Installation](https://github.com/angular/material2#installation). Otherwise you need to wait until they publish it to npm.

Comment: Ok Thanks Michael

Comment: Michael: After updating the angular to  v4.0.0 after running the app i browser i am getting following warning message.Template parse warnings:
The <template> element is deprecated. Use <ng-template> instead ("[WARNING ->]<template><div class="mat-autocomplete-panel" role="listbox" [id]="id" [ngClass]="_getClassList()" #p"): ng:///MdAutocompleteModule/MdAutocomplete.html@0:0

Comment: @Vignesh you need to use `<ng-template>` instead of `<template>` as the error says.

Comment: I am not using template @Michael

Comment: Then that should be a question on its own where you supply the necessary code and information. I'm also not the right person to ask about angular.